# Breeze 1.3.5 localStorage "The system cannot find the path specified"

Tags: local-storage, breeze

I had downloaded the "TempHire" example and ran with IE 10 (Windows 8). The next error appeared in `breeze.debug.js`:

```
Unhandled exception at line 13707, column 13 in http://localhost:49795/scripts/breeze.debug.js

0x80070003 - JavaScript runtime error: The system cannot find the path specified.
```

The section of error:

```
if (typeof (localStorage) != 'undefined') {
        var mongoMachineId = parseInt(localStorage['mongoMachineId']); //The error appeared here
        if (mongoMachineId >= 0 && mongoMachineId <= 16777215) {
            machine = Math.floor(localStorage['mongoMachineId']);
        }
        // Just always stick the value in.
        localStorage['mongoMachineId'] = machine;
        document.cookie = 'mongoMachineId=' + machine + ';expires=Tue, 19 Jan 2038 05:00:00 GMT';
    }
```

The problem is `typeof (localStorage) != 'undefined'` was `true` because `typeof (localStorage)` was equal `'unknown'` when the exception "`The system cannot find the path specified.`" appeared.

I didn't know how to reproduce this error exactly, because maybe It was random error of localStorage.

I had deleted all browser history and all work fine again, but later the error persist in IE10, Google Chrome 27 and Firefox21.

Please any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a bug in 1.3.5 related to something similar.  Please try out 1.3.6, available now, on the Breeze Web Site. I think it will fix the issue.